# Шаблонизация в kvm

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, виртуализация, kvm

Допустим, существует некий абстрактный сервер с centos 7 и kvm на борту. Мне нужно как-то (полу-)автоматизировать процесс разворачивания виртуальных машин при этом НЕ превращать процесс в конвейер (читать как foreman, proxmox, ovirt и иже с ними). В идеале, нужно получить bash-скрипт, принимающий параметрами ip адрес (либо адреса и имена интерфейсов соответственно) и hostname/vm_name. Высшая цель - провизионинг с помощью puppet. Пока из вариантов у меня есть

- cloud image (без демона, при помощи подгрузки временного iso в cdrom)
- virt-builder/virt-install: но я не знаю простого способа задать настройки сети на этапе билда или разворачивания машины
- kickstart: это вообще плохой вариант из-за бессмысленного ожидания процесса установки, - это избыточная процедура

В общем, буду рад вариантам, либо, может кто подскажет как сетевые настройки менять машине на этапе создания.

Comment: вопрос слишком глобален и расплывчат. конкретизируйте его, пожалуйста, чтобы он отвечал [критериям сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Но в приведённом тексте по Вашей ссылке нет ничего о "глобальности вопроса", а по сему, полагаю, правилам ресурса он не противоречит. Меня он интересует именно в том виде, в котором задан.

Comment: этот сайт, в первую очередь — база знаний. и лишь во вторую — средство получения ответов на свои частные вопросы. пожалуйста, уважайте тех, кого могут заинтересовать точно такие же вопросы, как и те, что встали перед вами. т.е.: задавайте **конкретный** вопрос, описывающий **конкретную** проблему. о чём и написано по приведённой ссылке.

Comment: И это великолепно, если база знаний пополнится **вариантами шаблонизации машин KVM**. Пожалуйста, уважайте тех, кто вопрошает НЕ пытаясь изменить вопрос на то, что не интересует автора, я это за Вами наблюдаю уже не первый год. То, что написано по ссылке - лишь **советы**, позволяющие увеличить шансы на ответ. Я не против, если шансы немного снизятся. Найти оптимальный метод того, что топике - вполне конкретный вопрос. Как только он будет определён, и в случае если с ним возникнут проблемы - будет задан более узкий вопрос, но не раньше. И всё равно спасибо за совет! ^_^

Comment: https://forge.puppet.com/tags/kvm ?

Comment: К сожалению, все те модули (их 3 всего под мою версию puppet) нужны для провизионинга, я же пока нахожусь на этапе создания образа машины. Например, берём любой модуль оттуда, и при объявлении домена, он просит указать dev (место, откуда будет загружаться машина), допустим, _/dev/vm-pool/my-domain.img_ , так вот мне нужно найти легкий метод, как создать этот _my-domain.img_ и только потом уже делать с ним что-то puppet'ом или чем-то ещё.
Наверно Александр в чём-то был прав и лучше бы провести декомпозицию вопроса...

Answer (score 1):

Возникала похожая задача с целью ускорения развертывания гостевых систем на базе готового шаблона. Принцип описан для работы с QEMU через Libvirt. Думаю, для голого QEMU можно реализовать похожий принцип.

Для себя решаю задачу следующим образом:

1. Создается обычная гостевая система с необходимым набором настроек. Нормальное состояние - выключена. При необходимости, я ее запускаю и вношу изменения. Это машина шаблон. Можно назвать соответствующим образом.

Технически это обычная гостевая машина. Состоит из двух файлов: образ диска и XML файл конфигурации, которые хранятся в каталоге этой машины. Все машины всегда имеют свой XML файл конфигурации!

2. Гостевая машина клонируется из шаблонной машины:

2.1. Создается новый каталог c новым именем, в это каталог копируются XML и образ диска с новыми именами равнами имени новой машины.

```
    mkdir /path/to/newvmname
    rsync -arutS /path/to/templatevm /path/to/newvmname
```

Ключ S нужен, чтобы правильно обрабатывать Sparse файлы для экономии дискового пространства и ускорения процесса. Файлы надо переименовать под имя новой машины, чтобы не было потом путаницы.

2.2. В новом конфиге XML /path/to/newvmname/newvmname.xml обязательно исправляются: UUID, NAME, MAC, свободный VNC port и пути к образу диска.

```
    vi /path/to/newvmname/newvmname.xml
```

2.3. образ диска монтируется с помощью libguestfs-tools (для Linux гостевых систем) и внутри образа исправляется hostname, примерно так:

```
    mkdir /mnt/newvmname
    guestmount -a /path/to/newvmname/newvmname.qcow2 -i  /mnt/newvmname
```

Исправили и размонтировали.

2.4. Делается добавление новой машины в libvirt и запускается:

```
    virsh define /path/to/newvmname/newvmname.xml
    virsh start newvmname
```

Мы выкатили машину из шаблона.

В сети работает DHCP DDNS, поэтому неважно какой адрес будет присвоен - дальнейшая работа с гостевой машиной ведется через DNS имя хоста.

Общий смысл такой. Конечно эта операция давно автоматизирована скриптом, у которого два параметра: имя шаблона и имя новой машины.